# Where do I persist the Spotify access token?

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

So I have got all my auth working in my MVC web site but I want to ask: What is the recommended way to pass the access token around in my application?

So, I click login, a dialog pops up and I log in. My parent window receives the access token and I get some playlists. But what if I go to another page, which would be a completely new request? Do I pass it around on the query string, or in session, or maybe a cookie? I have searched the API documentation for this, but cant find anything about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say you should store it in the side from which you are making the requests. If the requests are done client-side, then keep the access token client-side. You can persist it using `localStorage`, as done in the [web api player example](https://github.com/possan/webapi-player-example/blob/b6caa5969e6fb29c4fd974e5fec90285fb11f97a/services/auth.js#L53). That way you can read from localStorage when you need to make a request and use it until it expires.

Then, if you have used the [authorization code flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow) you will want to refresh it, so the user doesn't need to log in every 60 minutes. For this, you will need to make a request from your server, since the refresh process involves sending a secret that you don't want to make available in the browser. You can store the refresh token in the server (e.g. in a database table storing user <-> refresh token) or in the browser's localStorage too, sending it to the server when you want to refresh it.

You could also store it as a cookie, but if the server doesn't need to know about it, localStorage is better.

Comment: late comment, but is there any security vulnerabilities storing it in localStorage?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Identity will be holding all the details about the logged in User. If anything we want extra , we can extend it.

Below link may help :
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/574576/How-to-implement-a-custom-IPrincipal-in-ASP-NET-MV